# Mouse and keyboard don't work after update

Tags: 14.04, updates, keyboard, mouse

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I got some updates today and after installing them restarted the pc. The mouse and keyboard don't work anymore. I was able to get them working when I got into BIOS. The mouse and keyboard both work on other BIOS. It just stopped working after the updates.

Comment: Please, provide more description, like if mouse and keyboard are internal (laptop), or PS2 or wireless, etc.

Comment: I have a desktop pc, both mouse and keyboard are attached with usb.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem. I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on a Dell desktop computer (Inspiron 3847), Usb mouse and keyboard. The problem appeared today, after rebooting. Both keyboard and mouse are working with grub, but they stop working as soon as the kernel is loaded (3.13.0-48-generic). The same happens if I try to boot in recovery mode. Same story with 3.13.0-46-generic. I managed to have both mouse and keyboard working only using kernel 3.13.0-45-generic. At that point I tried to follow the strategy suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unrespons

Answer (score 1):

(I can't add comment to an answer, because of low rep)
I'm the one that reported the bug a few days ago.  You should click the button that say this bug affect me too to mark the bug as confirmed.

(Solution / Workarround)
Like I said in the bug report, the previous kernel is working.  By default, Ubuntu doesn't remove previous installed kernel.  You can select the previous working kernel in grub (you may have to press escape to get the grub boot menu).