# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes seconds after boot, stuck at login screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, kernel, freeze, mate

### Background

Two weeks ago,
I was on the kernel `4.13.0-36`, and
a routine update installed `4.13.0-37`
and `4.13.0-38` automatically. After that, I was unsuccessful in getting my laptop to boot beyond the login screen [(this is a documented bug affecting several users)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920).
I fixed (temporarily solved) it by removing `-37, -38`, and `apt-mark hold`ing -36. I continued to boot in `-36` without any issues for about two weeks now.

### Problem

I used my laptop as usual last night and then eventually shut it down. I believe I ran some routine updates through `apt`. Today morning I was unable to boot past the login screen.

Situation: My `grub` pops up by default. Then I choose the top option, which is `-36`. It runs through the boot process, asking me to unlock cryptswap. I do that. It finishes up, shows the login screen. Irrespective of whether or not I interact with it (e.g., moving the cursor around, typing my password really quick, or even booting into `tty2` or any other `tty`), it freezes in the next 6 seconds or so.

My current suspicion is that the problem must be caused by some recent package that was updated, or something to do with the kernels. Whatever it is, is crashing at login while trying to launch GUI. If I understand correctly, it is likely to be some process that occurs at startup.

#### Things I have tried without much luck

- `nomodeset` option: no luck with `-37, -38`, but `-36` boots. Can't suspend.
- `-36` recovery boot, and then trying to dpkg repair packages
- `chroot` followed by `apt upgrade` (according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/837219) answer)
- reinstalling `-37, -38` because apparently "a fix was committed" at the same link to the bug above. (tried `nomodeset` with all these kernels, too, didn't work)
- switching to another `tty`: doesn't work because machine freezes irrespective of what you do within 5-6 seconds

#### Logs and info

I'm just trying to provide down here anything I think is relevant. If you believe something else might help, please let me know and I'll be happy to upload it.

- DMESG output through `chroot` session (link redacted)
- Auth log for one such failed boot (link redacted)
- `dpkg` log from the last successful graphical session (yesterday) (1. all: link redacted; 2. only recently installed, filtered using `grep "install"`: link redacted)
- `syslog` from one such failed boot (link redacted)
- Basic information about hardware using `lspci` (link redacted)

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same on 17.10. Although you are on 16.04, the freeze seems to be common to both versions and may be [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1751584) or [that issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1760377).

```
sudo apt purge intel-microcode
```

suggested did *not* work for me but installing latest mainline kernel 4.16.3-041603-generic did solve the freeze. I used [ukuu](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html) to easily install this kernel, great utility!

Comment: I'm currently trying this out: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920, and later planning to try your solution.

Comment: `rm`'ing `intel-microcode` seems to do the trick. However, I haven't gone as far ahead to install the 4.16.x kernel(s). I read that 4.13.39-x was released which seems to be fixing this bug, but I'm probably going to avoid an update at this point and remain on this stable state

Comment: Also, I didn't _just_ `rm` it, but I also reinstalled the older version of `intel-microcode`
(See the "workaround" part of the following entry: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920)

Comment: `sudo apt purge intel-microcode` seems to work  for me too