# 16.04 Laptop Keyboard freezes on Lid Close, how do I get it back?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu

Asus laptop with i5-3230m cpu.  Everytime I close the lid the keyboard locks.  The only solution I have found is to hibernate, which is really just a quicker reboot.  Is there anything I can do to remedy the lost keyboard on lid close?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend

Comment: @David Wilkins This is not a duplicate, I have used 14.04 for two years with no issues.  It is strictly related to the new release.  None of the answers on this site or anywhere else on the internet address this issue.

Comment: Fair enough.  Hope you find the fix.