# trackpad freezes after suspend

Tags: touchpad

after i suspend my computer, my track-pad is non-responsive. the keypad, however still works.

i have tried the solution offered here
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182922

and here
[Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend)

since i have the same exact problem when i try to use tails with  this computer, i wonder if it's something with the track-pad driver?

ubuntu 16.04 xenial
lenovo yoga 900

thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to tty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: @HunterBolin You can set this answer as correct

Comment: So after 3 days, this solution no longer works. I now have to use a usb mouse,  which is not an ideal situation. this time, the cursor of the mouse doesn't even show up at all. i've tried restarting several times, tried the ctrl/alt/f1 and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```