# Trackpad and keyboard inoperative after suspend in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, suspend, touchpad, acer

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Acer Aspire R5-471T with a Synaptics SynPS/2 touchpad. When I suspend and unsuspend, the trackpad and keyboard are frequently nonresponsive when I return. (This does not, however, happen all the time, and I'm unsure what distinguishes the times it happens from the times it doesn't).

The touchscreen, and a mouse I plug in sometimes, continue to work in this event. I usually just use them to reboot, as that's the only thing I know that brings back functionality.

I have seen the closely related post [Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend) about a computer running 14.04 and tried all the solutions, but none have helped (I updated "utopic" to "xenial" in the package names in one of the solutions). I consider this to be a distinct problem because the version number is different, the previous solutions don't help, and the problem is intermittent rather than invariable. This question is also posted at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333042.

Comment: For touchpad you can try this solution https://code44free.wordpress.com/2016/08/18/ubuntu-16-04-fix-to-touchpad-not-working-after-suspend-problem/

Comment: It had worked fine since last time (although I did have to keep reenabling click-to-tap), but today when I resumed, both keyboard and trackpad worked for a fraction of a second, then stopped responding.