# Mechanical Keyboard (Aukey KM-G9) doesn't work after suspend. Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: keyboard, suspend, 17.04

When I put on sleep my desktop computer, when I resume my keyboard (Aukey KM-G9) doesn't work. If I unplug and than plug it again, then it works. 
I'm currently using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 but I've got the same problem with 16.04.

Edit: I've tried my old keyboard and It does work after suspend. I don't know why with my new I've got this strange issue. The new one is a mechanical keyboard.

---

Here's the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c246 Logitech, Inc. Gaming Mouse G300
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04d9:a0cd Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04e8:6124 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd D3 Station External Hard Drive
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

Here's `dmesg`

```
[  504.725733] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[  504.726015] Suspended for 3.327 seconds
[  504.726588] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  504.737759] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[  504.737760] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[  504.740110]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[  504.740186] microcode: sig=0x306a9, pf=0x2, revision=0x15
[  504.740448] microcode: updated to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[  504.740515] CPU1 is up
[  504.749709] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[  504.752082]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[  504.752502] CPU2 is up
[  504.765719] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[  504.768096]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[  504.768917] CPU3 is up
[  504.771282] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  504.790007] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  504.790055] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  504.790097] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  504.790130] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  504.790158] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 18.442 msecs
[  504.790438] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.248 msecs
[  504.790626] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  504.790677] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
[  504.790678] usb usb6: root hub lost power or was reset
[  504.792657] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is down
[  504.853346] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  504.853865] serial 00:06: activated
[  504.855289] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  504.855304] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[  505.167929] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  505.168077] ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  505.227852] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  505.227868] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  505.227885] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  505.227904] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  505.227920] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  505.228478] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  505.228480] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[  505.228482] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[  505.228708] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[  505.236331] ata3.00: disabling queued TRIM support
[  505.240993] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  505.240995] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[  505.240996] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[  505.241220] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[  505.248841] ata3.00: disabling queued TRIM support
[  505.249738] usb 5-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  505.253066] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  505.253141] ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[  506.845522] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  506.856069] ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  506.856071] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[  506.856073] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[  506.915860] ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  506.915863] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[  506.915865] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[  506.952740] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  507.807435] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[  507.807436] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[  507.807438] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: EEE is enabled
[  526.032945] usbhid 5-1:1.2: reset_resume error -110
[  526.033090] PM: resume of devices complete after 21243.710 msecs
[  526.033301] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[  526.033302] Restarting tasks ... 
[  526.033467] pci_bus 0000:05: Allocating resources
[  526.033487] pci 0000:04:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 05] add_size 1000
[  526.033490] pci 0000:04:00.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 05] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  526.033493] pci 0000:04:00.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 05] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  526.033497] pci 0000:04:00.0: res[14]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[  526.033499] pci 0000:04:00.0: res[14]=[mem 0x00100000-0x002fffff] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[  526.033501] pci 0000:04:00.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[  526.033503] pci 0000:04:00.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x002fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
[  526.033505] pci 0000:04:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[  526.033507] pci 0000:04:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[  526.033510] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[  526.033511] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[  526.033514] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  526.033515] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  526.033517] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[  526.033518] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[  526.033521] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[  526.033523] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[  526.033525] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  526.033526] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  526.033529] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[  526.033530] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[  526.033533] pci 0000:04:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[  526.046611] done.
[  526.046622] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[  526.203481] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[  526.358290] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[  529.389918] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[  529.389940] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[  529.389942] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: EEE is enabled
[  529.389961] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[  538.107665] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  538.109247] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.0002: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
[  539.151869] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  539.366001] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=a0cd
[  539.366003] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  539.366005] usb 5-1: Product: USB Keyboard
[  539.371653] input: USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04D9:A0CD.0006/input/input16
[  539.428241] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.0006: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:06:00.0-1/input0
[  549.583676] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.0007: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[  549.583704] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.0007: timeout initializing reports
[  549.583903] input: USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:06:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04D9:A0CD.0007/input/input17
[  549.643667] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:06:00.0-1/input1
[  549.646826] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.0008: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:06:00.0-1/input2
```

Comment: Assuming it's a USB keyboard, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/948982/edit) and give us the output of `lsusb` in a code block (`{}` button). Does it change when the keyboard doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend)

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/948982/edit) and provide the output of `dmesg` after the issue occured in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: Ok just edited.

Comment: Did you try [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280574/246819)?

Comment: yes, I've tried it but doesn't work with that code, how do I know what I what text I have to put after  usbhid.quirks ?

Comment: How about `0003:04D9:A0CD.0007` (see `dmesg` output)?

Comment: So, I have to change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT   with  usbhid.quirks=0003:04D9:A0CD.0007   ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64289/discussion-between-dessert-and-greenbarbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem by adding a simple string to boot option.

Fist of all, open terminal and type

```
lsusb
```

this command will display the USB devices.
The Aukey KM-G9 it's named **Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.** write down the *ID*, in my case is 04d9:a0cd, it's splitted in two by a colon ( : )

Then, type on the Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Here we have the config of grub, be careful.

Change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT with this kind of string:

```
usbhid.quirks=0x*ID_before_colon*:0x*ID_after_colon*:0x00000008
```

save the file, then in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot the computer

*this should be fix this strange situation. I think it's something related to the keyboard compatibility with the Linux Kernel.*