# Mechanical keyboard Sharkoon PureWriter not working after resume from suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend

My problem is similar to this:
[Mechanical Keyboard (Aukey KM-G9) doesn't work after suspend. Ubuntu Gnome 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948982/mechanical-keyboard-aukey-km-g9-doesnt-work-after-suspend-ubuntu-gnome-17-04)

I'm using ubuntu 18.04

On my Lenovo Legion Y530 there is no option disabling on BIOS about resuming from sleep with usb device.

On windows 10 when I get to sleep everything works fine.

edit: When my laptop is in suspend mode and I press key of sharkoon Ubuntu system is resuming but keyboard doesn't work.
With old non-mechanical keyboard is ok on ubuntu.

I was trying quirks but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think Intel virtual technology  was a problem. When I resume from suspend from power button works good.

Maybe it was connected with graphics card driver. I update to nvidia 440.

Comment: Don't work when I resume from keyboard key.