# Mechanical Keyboard Not Working?

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, keyboard, suspend

I have the Sharkoon purewriter keyboard. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. The keyboard doesn't work after resume. Often it doesn't work in grub, and the last few boots, it didn't even work at login.

I have had it connected to a powered [STLab USB 3.0 hub](https://ksp.co.il/?uin=30349&appkey=1006). Now I have plugged it directly into the PC USB slots. It seems to be working, but I didn't try suspend yet. Is there a way to get it working with the USB hub?

I see someone else had this [same issue with this keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197007/mechanical-keyboard-sharkoon-purewriter-not-working-after-resume-from-suspend), but there are no answers.

An additional search showed me this problem is common with all mechanical keyboards and ubuntu. But the [solution given](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1335007.html) didn't work for me.

[This solution](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend-ram) didn't work either. Run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

the edit the following line
from: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset i8042.nomux"`

Help please!

Comment: Check if the issue persists when you solely use the keyboard on the PC USB slots, then update your question accordingly. Please add the link to the "someone else had the same issue" question.

Comment: I have issues on occasion with my beloved model M (IBM) keyboard after suspend, however the issue is OS independent I concluded (doesn't matter what OS/release is running, including *live* systems on thumb-drive).  In my case I just disconnect the cable at the back of the keyboard & re-connect it, and all is good. It's no fix, just my workaround (*been using it for years; acts the same with other model M keyboards too so it's related to just one keyboard*).

Comment: Yes, I've plugged the keyboard directly into the PCs USB slots, and the keyboard still does't work after resume.

Comment: I've updated my comments to include the other answers I found.