# Keyboard mouse won't respond after lock Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, lts

Problem:   Keyboard mouse won't respond after lock Ubuntu 16.04

System Details: 
Asus X552C Laptop (4 GB RAM,250 GB for ext4, 6 GB for swap space)
Mediatech MTK 
Regular English Keyboard & Logitech Mouse
Fresh Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Issue Details: 
I've set the Screen-Lock for 2 min.
After locking, I need to enter the password to unlock the screen.

Intermittently, Alphabet keys on the keyboard just won't respond. I cannot enter the password. Mouse intermittently works, I can click on the right most Arrow button on the password field, which will give me the error message "Invalid password".

On a related note, I installed Sublime Text3, Alphabet keys won't respond, but capslock, tab, enter, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V works..
All keys work fine in VIM, GEdit, ...

It is tuff to pinpoint the problem to either NVidia Graphics, Xserver-org, ...

Any pointers would be helpful.

Note: I'm only powering off & then powering on the laptop on each occurrence of this issue.

Comment: Look at [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend). Even being a very old page, it may solve your problem. It's worth trying.

Comment: Have tried it, put it subtly "It is tuff to pinpoint the problem to either NVidia Graphics, Xserver-org, ...", ......broken packages & too many dependencies within x11-server*, vmmousem ... * *nvidia*....