# Ubuntu freezes when closing and reopening laptop lid

Tags: nvidia, gnome, laptop, freeze

My Ubuntu laptop (Asus K501UX, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) freezes after closing and reopening the lid.
Black screen is shown, no mouse or anything – only thing I can do is Alt-SysReq- R/E/I/S/U/B to force reboot it. I can’t Ctrl-Alt-F1.

I  have a GeForce GTX 950M with NVIDIA driver nvidia-384. Nouveau is blacklisted since I had to setup Cuda on this machine. My display manager is lightdm.

I have tried multiple solutions (using special boot options or installing xscreensaver like [Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend)) with no success.

Here is what happens in /var/log/syslog during the operation, before I reboot :

```
Nov 19 17:54:06 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110446.9818] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping') [100 110 37]
Nov 19 17:54:06 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:06] offline
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.0833] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping') [110 30 37]
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:50c0:2eb1:9714:f5e8 on wlp3s0.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:4b01:ceea:de09:8acf on wlp3s0.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:4b01:ceea:de09:8acf.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617 on wlp3s0.*.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617 on wlp3s0.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.1175] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1222
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.1175] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.1178] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  734.100195] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.188 on wlp3s0.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.188.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.1268] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: configuration des serveurs amonts à partir de DBus
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: utilise le serveur de nom 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:5e35:3bff:fe53:d3c6#53 (via wlp3s0)
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:07] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: p2p-dev-wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.1330] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: configuration des serveurs amonts à partir de DBus
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX dbus[813]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <warn>  [1511110447.1575] sup-iface[0x110cf80,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.1575] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110447.1581] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX dbus[813]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:07] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov 19 17:54:07 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Nov 19 17:54:08 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3995]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Nov 19 17:54:08 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]: Suspending system...
Nov 19 17:54:08 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  734.995986] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Nov 19 17:54:08 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  735.156938] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.160153] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.161885] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.162697] PM: Suspending system (mem)
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.162734] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.203346] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.203456] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.203637] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.203676] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  737.204502] ACPI : EC: event blocked
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.420997] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1218.168 msecs
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.442684] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 21.684 msecs
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.442924] ACPI : EC: interrupt blocked
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.443809] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.482721] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 40.034 msecs
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.483070] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.495771] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.495771] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.495900] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.497796] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.512627] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.536131] Broke affinity for irq 1
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.536138] Broke affinity for irq 8
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.536143] Broke affinity for irq 9
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.536148] Broke affinity for irq 12
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.536156] Broke affinity for irq 16
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.536161] Broke affinity for irq 17
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.536173] Broke affinity for irq 109
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.537281] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.554544] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.554650] ACPI : EC: EC started
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.554651] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.555459] Suspended for 4.430 seconds
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.555518] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.566844] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.566845] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.567411]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.567576] CPU1 is up
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.582879] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.583900]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.584271] CPU2 is up
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.602962] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.604003]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.604386] CPU3 is up
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.612006] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.638817] ACPI : EC: interrupt unblocked
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.679064] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.679362] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 40.709 msecs
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.692920] PM: early resume of devices complete after 13.508 msecs
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.693089] ACPI : EC: event unblocked
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.693263] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.693339] rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.695155] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.695168] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.716152] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.720538] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  738.974821] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  739.011156] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  739.012940] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  739.458916] PM: resume of devices complete after 765.992 msecs
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  739.459555] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX acpid: client 914[0:0] has disconnected
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX systemd[1380]: Time has been changed
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  739.459557] Restarting tasks ... done.
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]: System resumed.
Nov 19 17:54:16 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  740.838810] [drm] RC6 on
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  740.870537] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  740.873815] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]: /dev/sda:
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]:  APM_level#011= 254
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]: /dev/sdb:
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[3993]:  APM_level#011= 254
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd-sleep[4068]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit is bound to inactive unit systemd-suspend.service. Stopping, too.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110458.9472] manager: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110458.9472] manager: waking up...
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs at resume.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110458.9474] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX anacron[4143]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-11-19
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX anacron[4143]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110458.9799] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.535563] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.537659] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
Nov 19 17:54:18 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.537853] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.603342] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.603537] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.618171] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110459.0635] device (enp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.619141] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110459.0818] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.636666] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.636718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp3s0 flags: No such device
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110459.1246] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110459.1247] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Nov 19 17:54:19 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  741.680296] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7589] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7599] policy: auto-activating connection 'Alberich'
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7609] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Alberich' (fc1f9c78-aa7b-46a1-b6ac-f591dd8b5323)
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7612] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7614] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7624] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7627] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Alberich' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7627] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7667] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7670] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7672] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Alberich' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7673] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Alberich'
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7673] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7673] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7673] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7673] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Nov 19 17:54:22 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110462.7685] sup-iface[0x1111630,wlp3s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 (SSID='Alberich' freq=2412 MHz)
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  746.300981] wlp3s0: authenticate with 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 (SSID='Alberich' freq=2412 MHz)
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  746.303902] wlp3s0: send auth to 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 (try 1/3)
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  746.305990] wlp3s0: authenticated
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  746.306609] wlp3s0: associate with 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 (try 1/3)
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7510] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7560] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  746.310603] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  746.314097] wlp3s0: associated
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX kernel: [  746.314134] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: wlp3s0: Associated with 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7642] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX wpa_supplicant[1017]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 80:1f:02:bf:f9:50 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7804] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7804] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Alberich'.
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7805] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7808] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110463.7818] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 4152
Nov 19 17:54:23 amaury-K501UX dhclient[4152]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.188 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3bc464ac)
Nov 19 17:54:25 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617.
Nov 19 17:54:25 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Nov 19 17:54:25 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617 on wlp3s0.*.
Nov 19 17:54:25 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110465.4607] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 19 17:54:25 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110465.4617] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 4157
Nov 19 17:54:25 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:25] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dhclient[4157]: XMT: Info-Request on wlp3s0, interval 940ms.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dhclient[4157]: RCV: Reply message on wlp3s0 from fe80::5e35:3bff:fe53:d3c6.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1818]   nameserver '2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:5e35:3bff:fe53:d3c6'
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1818]   domain search 'home.'
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1818] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1839] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dbus[813]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1845] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): client pid 4157 exited with status 0
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1847] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1863] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1868] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.1872] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dbus[813]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.2913] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.2915] policy: set 'Alberich' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.2917] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: configuration des serveurs amonts à partir de DBus
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: utilise le serveur de nom 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:5e35:3bff:fe53:d3c6#53 (via wlp3s0)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.3138] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:26] The default IPv6 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:26] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:26] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:4b01:ceea:de09:8acf.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:4b01:ceea:de09:8acf on wlp3s0.*.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1ed0:2238:7637:4617 on wlp3s0.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:26] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dhclient[4152]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.188 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3bc464ac)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dhclient[4152]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.188 from 192.168.0.1
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5544]   address 192.168.0.188
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5545]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5545]   gateway 192.168.0.1
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5545]   server identifier 192.168.0.1
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5545]   lease time 3600
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.188.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5545]   hostname 'amaury-K501UX'
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5546]   nameserver '192.168.0.1'
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5546]   domain name 'home'
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5546] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.188 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5575] policy: set 'Alberich' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX NetworkManager[858]: <info>  [1511110466.5577] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: configuration des serveurs amonts à partir de DBus
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: utilise le serveur de nom 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:5e35:3bff:fe53:d3c6#53 (via wlp3s0)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dnsmasq[1274]: utilise le serveur de nom 192.168.0.1#53 (via wlp3s0)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:26] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX whoopsie[1365]: [17:54:26] online
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:3 'dhcp4-change' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX nm-dispatcher: req:3 'dhcp4-change' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX dhclient[4152]: bound to 192.168.0.188 -- renewal in 1793 seconds.
Nov 19 17:54:26 amaury-K501UX avahi-daemon[785]: Registering new address record for 2a02:810d:14c0:13a4:50c0:2eb1:9714:f5e8 on wlp3s0.*.
Nov 19 17:54:28 amaury-K501UX systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
```

Thank you !